# Audio Engine for City Simulation Game for Python

Tags: open-source, python, audio, game-development

## Software suggestion:

- I need a **Audio Engine** which facilitates ***my requirements.***
- **City Simulation** means building a city from plain land. Or **City Building Game** which is same as **City Simulation!**

---

### Requirements:

**1. Free**
**2. Open-source**
**3. Easy to use**
**4. Compatible with Python**
**5. 3D audio support**

---

#### Thank you.

Comment: I think this is the question for https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: When i ask they just closed this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panda3D is free, open-source, easy to use, compatible with Python, and supports 3D audio. It also provides 3D rendering if you need that for your game too.

https://www.panda3d.org/